# What's the fastest way to remove or change large number of entries in arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, nan

I want to change a number of values in a 4D array *M*_ *ijkl* to NaN using MATLAB.
I use `find` to get the indices *i* and *j* that meet a certain condition for *k* = 2 and *l* = 4 (in my case it's the *y* component of a position at time *t*_4). I now want to set all the entries for these *i* and *j* combinations and for all *k* and *l* to NaN.

I used this method to do it (example by nkjt):

```
% initialise
M = zeros(10,10,2,4);

% set two points in (:,:,2,4) to be above threshold. 
M(2,4,2,4)=5; 
M(6,8,2,4)=5; 

% find and set to NaN
[i,j] = find(M(:,:,2,4) > 4);
M(i,j,:,:)= NaN;

% count NaNs
sum(isnan(M(:)))   % returns 32
```

This method is is very slow as this example illustrates:

```
M = rand(360,360,2,4);
threshold = 0.5;

% slow and wrong result
[i,j] = find(M(:,:,2,4) > threshold);
tic;
M(i,j,:,:) = NaN;
toc;

Elapsed time is 54.698449 seconds.
```

Note that the `tic` and `toc` don't time the `find` so that is not the problem.

With Rody's and njkt's help I also realized that my method doesn't actually do what I want. I only want to change entries with the combinations *i* and *j* i found with `find` (for all *k* and *l*), i.e. `[2,4,:,:]` and `[6,8,:,:]`, but **not** `[2,8,:,:]` and `[6,4,:,:]`. In the first example `sum(isnan(M(:)))` should return 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much faster for me by reshaping M:

```
M = rand(360,360,2,4);
M = reshape(M,[360*360,2,4]);
maximum = 0.05;
n = find(M(:,2,4) > maximum);

tic;
M(n,:,:) = NaN;
M = reshape(M,[360, 360, 2, 4]);
toc;
```

ETA:

`M(i,j,:,:)= NaN`; sets all combinations of i, j to NaN for all k,l (as explained in Rody's answer).

So for example:

```
% initialise
M = zeros(10,10,2,4);

% set two points in (:,:,2,4) to be above threshold. 
M(2,4,2,4)=5; 
M(6,8,2,4)=5; 

% find and set to NaN
[i,j] = find(M(:,:,2,4) > 4);
M(i,j,:,:)= NaN;

% count NaNs
sum(isnan(M(:)))   % returns 32
```

e.g. '(2,4,l,k) = NaN' but also '(4,2,l,k) = NaN'.

If this is what you want, reduce the size of i,j with unique after `find`.

---

In terms of logical indexing, basically, it's often better to do something like `A(A>2)=NaN;` instead of `n = find(A>2); A(n)=NaN;`.  In the reshaped case you could do `M(M(:,2,4)>maximum,:,:) = NaN;`.  I didn't tic/toc it so I don't know if it would be faster in this case.

Comment: I don't really see why but this doesn't do the same thing as my code. I tested this by cloning `M` and and using both methods. `isequal` on the two resulting arrays returns `0`.

Comment: I looked into it a little bit. Your solution sets fewer entries to `NaN`. It doesn't change the columns (i,:,k,l).

Comment: That's weird; it worked for the toy problem you gave (including when I took it to M = 3 x 2 x 2 x 4).  Do you want all j for a given i to be NaN as well? My impression was that you wanted all l,k for a given (i,j). Note: `isequal` will never return 1 if comparing arrays containing NaNs, as `isequal(NaN,NaN)` is false.

Comment: I thought I wanted all _j_ for a given _i_ to be `NaN` as well, but I think that was actually wrong. So I think my original code wasn't doing what I thought it did. I think that your solution is actually doing what I am trying to accomplish... I don't have access to MATLAB right now so I'll have to compare Rody's and your solution later. And I'll probably have to rephrase my question. Thanks so far!

Comment: Your code actually does what I want. Thank you!
MATLAB still warns me to use logical indexing instead of `fin` however.

Comment: @frankundfrei I think in this case you can simply remove `find`. Didn't check but if it still gives the result that you want it is likely to be a bit faster.

Comment: Logical indexing is about twice as fast as `find`. Both take far less than a second now on my computer in the example above, even with matrix dimensions 3600*3600*4*2 and `maximum = .00005`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your results? Because I think they are wrong. For example, if you have

```
A = [...
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9];
```

and you want to set element `A(1,1)` and `A(2,3)` to `NaN`. What you are doing is

```
A([1 2], [1 3]) = NaN
```

but that gives

```
A =
   NaN     2   NaN
   NaN     5   NaN
     7     8     9
```

The easiest and fastest way around this is to not use `find`, but logical indexing:

```
M = rand(360,360,2,4);
maximum = 0.05;
tic;
M(M(:,:,2,4) > maximum) = NaN;
toc
```

Which gives on my PC:

```
Elapsed time is 0.003547 seconds.
```

Comment: That was one of the attempts I tried. It doesn't do the same thing as my code however. Notice that my code deletes entries for all indices *k* and *l*, yours simply deletes the entries with *k*=2 and *l*=4.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read the first part of your answer...

Yes, I want to set all entries with indices *k* and *l* to NaN. That is the positions for all four times (index *l*) and both *x* and *y* component (index *k*) should be set to NaN.

Comment: @frankundfrei: I'm sorry, then I just misunderstood. And I'm still not quite sure I understand...Could you provide a small example of input and expected output?

Comment: I'll include a example of a similar problem. With a 4D array it is a little complicated...

Comment: I hope my illustration helps to understand my problem.

Comment: I'm thinking now that you might have actually been right... I thought my code does something different than it actually does. I'll look into it and probably rephrase my question when I have access to a MATLAB installation again. Then I'll compare your solution with nkjt's. Thanks!

Comment: I think I now figured out what I actually wanted to do. Your solution returns 2 for `sum(isnan(M(:)))` in the example above. So it only changes the values for *k* = 2 and _l_ = 4. I want all _k_ and _l_ to be changed for a given combination of _i_,_j_ to be changed. njkt's solution does what I want but I think it could still be made faster with logical indexing.